# Use Node Format - is this option redundant, or what?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, path, settings, output

Even though I use the **File Output Node** frequently, there's an option I've been ignoring but finally have to ask about:

### Use Node Format

The File Output Node seems to work just fine without this box ticked, so what does it do?

Apparently I'm not the only one. There is also [this decade old Blender Artists post](https://blenderartists.org/t/another-compositing-challenge-to-you-node-gurus/593988/3) where a user observes: *“I noticed an option to use node format… it was checked by default, so I just left it. But if anyone knows, why would you not have that checked?”* Nobody replied.

If I had to guess, I would suspect that the **Base Path** settings are global and apply to all inputs, whereas the **Subpath** settings are individualized for each local input - so this is only a consideration *if* you have more than one input *and* have enabled the **Use Node Format** option. But this is just my intuition, and I don't know much about the workflows of others using the File Output Node. The [Blender Manual's page on the File Output Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/output/file.html) doesn't presently go into detail about the two different sets of settings.

Assuming my above guess is accurate, it would be less confusing if enabling **Use Node Format** caused the **Base Path** settings to grey out. And if when disabled, the **File Subpath** settings would grey out.

I'm in the habit of using one File Output Node per image anyway (as opposed to a single one with multiple inputs). And that's probably why I've gone so long without thinking deeply about the two sets of settings. Now I have to wonder if there is any advantage to using a single File Output Node (memory conservation?). But I suppose that would be a separate question.

<sub>Screenshot of the File Output Node's settings in the N Panel (and scene Output settings) for reference:</sub>

[image: The File Output Node's settings in the N Panel (Properties Panel)]